# требуется написать код решения для задачи в три цикла

Tags: c

**[image: задание на листке]**

Вот что я пытался сделать:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main ()
{
    int res, m, n, sum;
    printf ("Enter numbers: \n");
    scanf ("%d", &m);
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 1; i == m; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j == n; j++){
            for (int k = 1; k <= abs(m-n); k++){
                 res = (m-n);
                 
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\t result=%d \n",sum);
}
```

Comment: Вы **точно** записали условие? Именно так? тогда циклы не нужны вовсе, это m\*n\*(m-n)! - просто потому, что вы суммируете константу... Может, сумма от (i-j)! ? но тогда учтите, что для целых отрицательных значений факториал (точнее, Г-функция) имеет значение минус бесконечность. Словом, в очередной раз продемонстрировано, что **без точного ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...**

Comment: Условие верное и задание написать в три цикла

Comment: Тогда препод идиот.

Answer (score 1):

еще хорошо бы попытаться прочитать что-то по языку c

1. в цикле первый блок - инициализация переменных (вызывается в начале цикла), второй блок - условия продолжения цикла (вызывается в начале каждого этапа цикла - если условие верно, то выполняется этап цикла иначе цикл прекращается), третий блок - изменение переменных в начале каждого этапа цикла

   ```
    for (int i = 1; i == m; i++){
   ```

   как вы думаете, сколько этапов цикла будет выполнено при `m = 10`?
2. что именно у вас происходит с переменной `res`?

   ```
     for (int k = 1; k <= abs(m-n); k++){
         res = (m-n);        
     }
   ```

   поскольку с `res` в дальнейшем ничего не происходит, то вы на выходе всех ваших циклов получаете последний `res` и все

**P.S.**

давайте разберемся что в данной формуле вообще записано:

1. вычислить `m` раз `(m - n)!` и сложить, т.е. вычислить `m * (m - n)!`
2. вычислить `n` раз то, что было вычислено в 1), т.е. вычислить `n * m * (m - n)!`

ну так и пляшите от этого

т.е. если вам требуется именно 3 цикла, то у вас должно быть:

```
окончательный результат равен 0
цикл по `i`
    цикл по `j`
        вычисляем `(m-n)!`
        складываем с окончательным результатом
```

**P.P.S.**

и кстати `abs(m - n)` совершенно не при чём - факториал от отрицательного числа вроде как не существует